# Difference between stop and terminate options of tomcat in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat6

What is the difference between stop and terminate options of tomcat in eclipse. I am using eclipse Kepler for Java EE.

What are their equivalent command line options in unix?

Does stop means stopping web application and terminate means stopping tomcat server ?

Edit : Terminate i can see in debug perspective , which is equivalent to terminating any java program. 
Now the doubt left is what stop does ? .if it is stopping tomcat how can i stop only webapp without stopping tomcat server.

Comment: It is not the answer but latest version of Eclipse is LUNA not Kepler.

Comment: where is terminate option? i cant see it on Server panel.

Comment: @HomayounAfshari Go to debug mode and right click on "Tomcatv6.0 Server at localhost[Apache Tomcat] , or just right click on "org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap at localhost:XXXXX" . You will find some variations of tomcat.

Comment: @HomayounAfshari I feel this terminate is just simple option to terminate any java program which is started.

Comment: @HomayounAfshari I have edited my question as got one part of answer after reading your comment :)

Comment: @Hoosier Who cares what the latest version is, (s)he is looking for help with Kepler, we are lucky enough to get someone to post version details.

Answer (score 2):

I had some troubles when stopping a Tomcat server instance using the "Stop the server" button and I felt curious about it.

I went into the Eclipse manual. I don't usually go there since there are a lot of good handy answers about it here at Stackoverflow. In particular, this page tells something about the difference between "Terminate" and "Stop the server":

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftwstpins.html

Extracting from the NOTE, it seems that **"Stop the server" tries to shutdown the server through the normal routine of stopping, for example calling the destroy() method on a servlet**.

So if you could call your webapps destroy() methods...that could be a way of shutting down applications without shutting the whole server.

Finally, I would recommend using "Terminate" if someone has problems with the normal process of "Stop the server", even though it is more abrupt.

Answer (score 0):

there is no option to stop a single webapp without stopping tomcat server. you can just undeploy the webapp by `remove` option.

Comment: "there is no option to stop a single webapp without stopping tomcat server" I hope u are talking about eclipse only , is there any link where you have seen this information ?